# Cardview with rounded corners background color

Tags: android, cardview

I have the cardview with rounded corners and imageview inside. I want to set background color :

```
cv.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
```

But the corners are not rounded in this case
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG4jg.jpg)

I tryed

```
cv.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
```

but in this case i can't see red color at all (with any margin and padding values)

Comment: Please post your xml file

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a `Drawable` and set it as the background for your `CardView`.

Lets say this is a drawable named `CardViewBackground`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_dark_red"/>
      <corners android:radius="10dp">
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

Then in my `CardView` I can do

```
<CardView....
    android:background="@drawable/CardViewBackground"
/>
```